# Reading file A and appending to file B, skipping some bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, filestream

I need to append a few BMP images together.  As you may know, BMP images have a 54-byte header.  I will write my own new header to a new file, then I need to loop through a list of BMP files and append them to each other, but I need to skip the first 54 bytes of each one.

This is for a gigapixel image stitching project.  I would use the software that already exists except there is no overlap in the images (but I know the tile layout).  I need to be able to take in some very large BMP files (192,000x1080) as rows and append them one below the other to create the final image, which is 20.7 gigapixels.  And while I have 32GB of memory, the final 20.7 gigapixel image is going to be 62.2GB (which I will then convert to PNG).

Given these huge memory requirements, how do I read each BMP and append them to the final file without using all of my memory?  I would like to use byte arrays if possible; because these are incompressed BMPs, they can be read like that and saved to another file without using any GDI objects.

Comment: >How do I read each BMP and append them to the final file without using all of my memory?

Stream the files.

Answer (score 4):

You can write to arbitrary locations in a file. To wit:

```
using(var s = new FileStream("myBigImage.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    //assume that you write out the header here
    foreach(var tileFile in tiles) {
        byte[] imgData = /*read image data into a byte[]*/;
        long y = /*obtain the correct y offset*/;

        s.Position = y * pixelWidth * imageWidth + 58;
        s.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

    }
}
```

Basically, you can jump around the file to fill in wherever you want. `Position` is a long value, so you don't have to worry about bumping into the limit of a 32-bit integer.

Luckily, because your image is basically just a tall stack of tiles, you don't have to worry about dealing with each individual line. In that case, to keep memory down, you would have to write out each tile's lines individually.

Comment: Did my response help at all? If so, an accepted answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hold all of the resulting file data in the memory. Just open a FileStream and write the data to file. FileStream does not use too much memory even if you write gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone after me is interested, here's what I found to work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reverseImageFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            string curBMP = reverseImageFiles[i];

            using(Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(curBMP))
            using (Stream writeStream = new FileStream(outputBMP,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None))
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(inStream);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

                byte[] buffer = new Byte[134217728];
                int bytesRead;
                int totalBytes = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 134217728)) > 0)
                {
                    totalBytes += bytesRead;

                    if (totalBytes <= 134217729)  //if it's the first round of reading to the buffer, you need to get rid of 54-byte BMP header
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 54, bytesRead - 54);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Two things:

Specifically for BMPs, I found out that you need to reverse the file list when appending.  For example, if the three files to be appended are labeled 001.bmp, 002.bmp, 003.bmp, where 001.bmp should be at the top, you need to actually start with 003.bmp and work down.  Apparently BMPs are encoded backwards.

**As you can see, I used a 128MB buffer.  Would it be better to use a different size if I wanted to reduce hard drive seeking?**  My drive has been recently defragged.  Thanks for all the help!